# Correct and efficient use of websockets?

Tags: javascript, web-services, sockets, websocket

I'm currently making plans for a real-time web application. More specifically, it will be an idle game where players can interact with each other. I will use a server storing messages sent from players to other players, which allows for communication when any party is not online.

The game page will load all game assets, such as images and static game data. There will be no need in reloading the page in any time. I'm planning to send more specific game data over web sockets (such as world map data). This may result in somewhat larger packets. I expect these packets to be in a range from very small (chat messages, 2kb) to very large (world data, 100~300 kb). I expect about 3 chat messages to be exchanged per minute per user, to be sent to a number of users (max 10~20). I expect that a user will receive a large set of data every minute or every two minutes.

I'm mainly interested in finding out what kind of performance-related issues may occur, and how to deal with these. A few questions coming to my mind are:

- Is it smart to use websockets in this way?
- Will it be better to use one socket or to use two sockets (one for small data fragments, one for big data fragments)? Socket connections will be made to the same server.
- What are hazards to keep in mind? (I do not mean backward compatability issues here)
- Compared to AJAX, do you expect differences in server load? Will these be significant?
- What are performance effects to the client and server?

Comment: you can use **MQTT protocol** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) instead of Websocket for smaller data transmissions.

Comment: @modernator For the clients, browserify converts these to websockets (see https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets, last line at the browser-section of readme.md). How does this increase the performance, compared to 'native' javascript websockets? It only seems to add complexity!